# Objective-C load Core Audio File sound file issue

Tags: objective-c

I try to load caf sound file from my app.
I use the following code to load caf sound file but I got exception.

**Note: I can load the wav or mp3 file without any issue with the same code.
I do check the caf sound file in the right directory from command line.**

```
    NSString *timeOutPath              = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"timeout" ofType:@"caf"];
  //NSString *timeOutPath              = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"timeout_tmp" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *timeOutURL                  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:timeOutPath];
    _soundTimeOut                      = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:timeOutURL error:nil];
    _soundTimeOut.numberOfLoops        = 1; // -1 is infinite
```

I got following exception:

```
+[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000109b0c157 -[NSURL(NSURL) initFileURLWithPath:] + 131
```

I would like to know whether I need to use **different code** to load caf file. It works fine for **wav** and **mp3** file

Comment: caf is a container format. What is the format of the sound inside the caf file? Does the caf file play OK in iTunes?

Comment: Yep, it play Ok in iTunes

Comment: `NSError *error = nil; [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:timeOutURL error:&error]; NSLog(@"Error: %@", error)` doesn't give an hint?

Comment: Sorry, I found out it is the path issue since I have two same sound wav files in different directory in my Xcode. "Copy Bundle Resources" uses different path wav file. I have similar experience with Visual Studio.  When you drag the resources files to Xcode or Visual Studio. You should never trust what the IDE will do.  It is impossible to figure what path they they will use.

Comment: By the way, I have some wav file play twice in my app. like repeating sound. do you have the experience before?  I debug it, the line of code is called only once.